# Qt4.natvis not working in VSCode on Centos 7

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, natvis

I am using VSCode to develop with Qt4 on Centos 7 over SSH.  My launch.json reads:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/debug/program",
            "args": ["--Verbose"],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                // {
                //     "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                //     "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                //     "ignoreFailures": false
                // }
            ],
            "visualizerFile": "/root/Qt4.natvis",
            "showDisplayString": true,
            "logging": {
                "engineLogging": true,
                "trace": true,
                "traceResponse": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When hovering over a QString named stmt some information is displayed in the pop-up, like the string size but there is no information on the actual text content.  The same is true in the watch window.  The main visualiser text reads "-var-create: unable to create variable object"

When I hover, the following stream of error messages are produced by gdb.

There are multiple instances of the "-var-create" error and an "Explicit refresh required for visualized expressions" error.

```
<--   C (evaluate-28): {"command":"evaluate","arguments":{"expression":"stmt","frameId":1000,"context":"hover"},"type":"request","seq":28}
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45371) <-1126-var-create - * \"stmt\"\n"},"seq":1556}
1: (45371) <-1126-var-create - * "stmt"
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45372) ->1126^done,name=\"var46\",numchild=\"2\",value=\"{...}\",type=\"QString\",thread-id=\"1\",has_more=\"0\"\n"},"seq":1558}
1: (45372) ->1126^done,name="var46",numchild="2",value="{...}",type="QString",thread-id="1",has_more="0"
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45373) ->(gdb)\n"},"seq":1560}
1: (45373) ->(gdb)
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45373) 1126: elapsed time 1\n"},"seq":1562}
1: (45373) 1126: elapsed time 1
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45373) <-1127-var-list-children --simple-values \"var46\" 0 1000\n"},"seq":1564}
1: (45373) <-1127-var-list-children --simple-values "var46" 0 1000
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45374) ->1127^done,numchild=\"2\",children=[child={name=\"var46.public\",exp=\"public\",numchild=\"1\",value=\"\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var46.private\",exp=\"private\",numchild=\"4\",value=\"\",thread-id=\"1\"}],has_more=\"0\"\n"},"seq":1566}
1: (45374) ->1127^done,numchild="2",children=[child={name="var46.public",exp="public",numchild="1",value="",thread-id="1"},child={name="var46.private",exp="private",numchild="4",value="",thread-id="1"}],has_more="0"
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45374) ->(gdb)\n"},"seq":1568}
1: (45374) ->(gdb)
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45374) 1127: elapsed time 1\n"},"seq":1570}
1: (45374) 1127: elapsed time 1
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45375) <-1128-var-list-children --simple-values \"var46.public\" 0 1000\n"},"seq":1572}
1: (45375) <-1128-var-list-children --simple-values "var46.public" 0 1000
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45379) ->1128^done,numchild=\"1\",children=[child={name=\"var46.public.null\",exp=\"null\",numchild=\"0\",type=\"const QString::Null\",thread-id=\"1\"}],has_more=\"0\"\n"},"seq":1574}
1: (45379) ->1128^done,numchild="1",children=[child={name="var46.public.null",exp="null",numchild="0",type="const QString::Null",thread-id="1"}],has_more="0"
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45379) ->(gdb)\n"},"seq":1576}
1: (45379) ->(gdb)
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45379) 1128: elapsed time 4\n"},"seq":1578}
1: (45379) 1128: elapsed time 4
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45379) <-1129-var-list-children --simple-values \"var46.private\" 0 1000\n"},"seq":1580}
1: (45379) <-1129-var-list-children --simple-values "var46.private" 0 1000
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45381) ->1129^done,numchild=\"4\",children=[child={name=\"var46.private.shared_null\",exp=\"shared_null\",numchild=\"1\",type=\"QString::Data\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var46.private.shared_empty\",exp=\"shared_empty\",numchild=\"1\",type=\"QString::Data\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var46.private.d\",exp=\"d\",numchild=\"1\",value=\"0x67a820\",type=\"QString::Data *\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var46.private.codecForCStrings\",exp=\"codecForCStrings\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"0x0\",type=\"QTextCodec *\",thread-id=\"1\"}],has_more=\"0\"\n"},"seq":1582}
1: (45381) ->1129^done,numchild="4",children=[child={name="var46.private.shared_null",exp="shared_null",numchild="1",type="QString::Data",thread-id="1"},child={name="var46.private.shared_empty",exp="shared_empty",numchild="1",type="QString::Data",thread-id="1"},child={name="var46.private.d",exp="d",numchild="1",value="0x67a820",type="QString::Data *",thread-id="1"},child={name="var46.private.codecForCStrings",exp="codecForCStrings",numchild="0",value="0x0",type="QTextCodec *",thread-id="1"}],has_more="0"
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45381) ->(gdb)\n"},"seq":1584}
1: (45381) ->(gdb)
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45381) 1129: elapsed time 2\n"},"seq":1586}
1: (45381) 1129: elapsed time 2
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45381) <-1130-var-create - * \"(const char16_t*)(((stmt).d)->data)\"\n"},"seq":1588}
1: (45381) <-1130-var-create - * "(const char16_t*)(((stmt).d)->data)"
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45382) ->1130^error,msg=\"-var-create: unable to create variable object\"\n"},"seq":1590}
1: (45382) ->1130^error,msg="-var-create: unable to create variable object"
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45382) ->(gdb)\n"},"seq":1592}
1: (45382) ->(gdb)
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45382) 1130: elapsed time 0\n"},"seq":1594}
1: (45382) 1130: elapsed time 0
--> R (evaluate-28): {"type":"response","request_seq":28,"success":true,"command":"evaluate","body":{"result":"-var-create: unable to create variable object","type":"QString","variablesReference":1012},"seq":1596}
<--   C (variables-29): {"command":"variables","arguments":{"variablesReference":1012},"type":"request","seq":29}
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45428) <-1131-var-create - * \"((stmt).d)->size\"\n"},"seq":1599}
1: (45428) <-1131-var-create - * "((stmt).d)->size"
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45430) ->1131^done,name=\"var48\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"129\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\",has_more=\"0\"\n"},"seq":1601}
1: (45430) ->1131^done,name="var48",numchild="0",value="129",type="int",thread-id="1",has_more="0"
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45430) ->(gdb)\n"},"seq":1603}
1: (45430) ->(gdb)
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45430) 1131: elapsed time 2\n"},"seq":1605}
1: (45430) 1131: elapsed time 2
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45430) <-1132-var-create - * \"((stmt).d)->ref._q_value\"\n"},"seq":1607}
1: (45430) <-1132-var-create - * "((stmt).d)->ref._q_value"
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45433) ->1132^done,name=\"var49\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"1\",type=\"volatile int\",thread-id=\"1\",has_more=\"0\"\n"},"seq":1609}
1: (45433) ->1132^done,name="var49",numchild="0",value="1",type="volatile int",thread-id="1",has_more="0"
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45433) ->(gdb)\n"},"seq":1611}
1: (45433) ->(gdb)
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45433) 1132: elapsed time 2\n"},"seq":1613}
1: (45433) 1132: elapsed time 2
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45434) <-1133-var-create - * \"((stmt).d)->size\"\n"},"seq":1615}
1: (45434) <-1133-var-create - * "((stmt).d)->size"
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45437) ->1133^done,name=\"var50\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"129\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\",has_more=\"0\"\n"},"seq":1617}
1: (45437) ->1133^done,name="var50",numchild="0",value="129",type="int",thread-id="1",has_more="0"
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45437) ->(gdb)\n"},"seq":1619}
1: (45437) ->(gdb)
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45437) 1133: elapsed time 3\n"},"seq":1621}
1: (45437) 1133: elapsed time 3
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45437) <-1134-var-create - * \"*(((stmt).d)->data,c)\"\n"},"seq":1623}
1: (45437) <-1134-var-create - * "*(((stmt).d)->data,c)"
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45438) ->1134^done,name=\"var51\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\",has_more=\"0\"\n"},"seq":1625}
1: (45438) ->1134^done,name="var51",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1",has_more="0"
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45438) ->(gdb)\n"},"seq":1627}
1: (45438) ->(gdb)
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45439) 1134: elapsed time 1\n"},"seq":1629}
1: (45439) 1134: elapsed time 1
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45439) <-1135-var-evaluate-expression var51\n"},"seq":1631}
1: (45439) <-1135-var-evaluate-expression var51
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45440) ->1135^done,value=\"\"\n"},"seq":1633}
1: (45440) ->1135^done,value=""
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45440) ->(gdb)\n"},"seq":1635}
1: (45440) ->(gdb)
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45440) 1135: elapsed time 1\n"},"seq":1637}
1: (45440) 1135: elapsed time 1
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45441) <-1136-var-create - * \"(int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c)\"\n"},"seq":1639}
1: (45441) <-1136-var-create - * "(int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c)"
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45442) ->1136^done,name=\"var52\",numchild=\"50\",value=\"[50]\",type=\"int [50]\",thread-id=\"1\",has_more=\"0\"\n"},"seq":1641}
1: (45442) ->1136^done,name="var52",numchild="50",value="[50]",type="int [50]",thread-id="1",has_more="0"
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45442) ->(gdb)\n"},"seq":1643}
1: (45442) ->(gdb)
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45442) 1136: elapsed time 1\n"},"seq":1645}
1: (45442) 1136: elapsed time 1
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45442) <-1137-var-list-children --simple-values \"var52\" 0 1000\n"},"seq":1647}
1: (45442) <-1137-var-list-children --simple-values "var52" 0 1000
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45445) ->1137^done,numchild=\"50\",children=[child={name=\"var52.0\",exp=\"0\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.1\",exp=\"1\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.2\",exp=\"2\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.3\",exp=\"3\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.4\",exp=\"4\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.5\",exp=\"5\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.6\",exp=\"6\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.7\",exp=\"7\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.8\",exp=\"8\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.9\",exp=\"9\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.10\",exp=\"10\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.11\",exp=\"11\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.12\",exp=\"12\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.13\",exp=\"13\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.14\",exp=\"14\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.15\",exp=\"15\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.16\",exp=\"16\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.17\",exp=\"17\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.18\",exp=\"18\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.19\",exp=\"19\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.20\",exp=\"20\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.21\",exp=\"21\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.22\",exp=\"22\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.23\",exp=\"23\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.24\",exp=\"24\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.25\",exp=\"25\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.26\",exp=\"26\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.27\",exp=\"27\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.28\",exp=\"28\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.29\",exp=\"29\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.30\",exp=\"30\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.31\",exp=\"31\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.32\",exp=\"32\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.33\",exp=\"33\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.34\",exp=\"34\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.35\",exp=\"35\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.36\",exp=\"36\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.37\",exp=\"37\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.38\",exp=\"38\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.39\",exp=\"39\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.40\",exp=\"40\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.41\",exp=\"41\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.42\",exp=\"42\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.43\",exp=\"43\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.44\",exp=\"44\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.45\",exp=\"45\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.46\",exp=\"46\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.47\",exp=\"47\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.48\",exp=\"48\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"},child={name=\"var52.49\",exp=\"49\",numchild=\"0\",value=\"\",type=\"int\",thread-id=\"1\"}],has_more=\"0\"\n"},"seq":1649}
1: (45445) ->1137^done,numchild="50",children=[child={name="var52.0",exp="0",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.1",exp="1",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.2",exp="2",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.3",exp="3",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.4",exp="4",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.5",exp="5",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.6",exp="6",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.7",exp="7",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.8",exp="8",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.9",exp="9",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.10",exp="10",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.11",exp="11",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.12",exp="12",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.13",exp="13",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.14",exp="14",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.15",exp="15",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.16",exp="16",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.17",exp="17",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.18",exp="18",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.19",exp="19",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.20",exp="20",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.21",exp="21",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.22",exp="22",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.23",exp="23",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.24",exp="24",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.25",exp="25",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.26",exp="26",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.27",exp="27",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.28",exp="28",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.29",exp="29",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.30",exp="30",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.31",exp="31",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.32",exp="32",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.33",exp="33",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.34",exp="34",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.35",exp="35",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.36",exp="36",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.37",exp="37",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.38",exp="38",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.39",exp="39",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.40",exp="40",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.41",exp="41",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.42",exp="42",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.43",exp="43",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.44",exp="44",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.45",exp="45",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.46",exp="46",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.47",exp="47",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.48",exp="48",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"},child={name="var52.49",exp="49",numchild="0",value="",type="int",thread-id="1"}],has_more="0"
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45445) ->(gdb)\n"},"seq":1651}
1: (45445) ->(gdb)
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45445) 1137: elapsed time 3\n"},"seq":1653}
1: (45445) 1137: elapsed time 3
--> E (output): {"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"1: (45446) Natvis failed to parse typename: volatile int\n"},"seq":1655}
1: (45446) Natvis failed to parse typename: volatile int
--> R (variables-29): {"type":"response","request_seq":29,"success":true,"command":"variables","body":{"variables":[{"name":"[size]","value":"129","type":"int","evaluateName":"((stmt).d)->size","variablesReference":0,"memoryReference":"0x0000000000000081"},{"name":"[referenced]","value":"1","type":"volatile int","evaluateName":"((stmt).d)->ref._q_value","variablesReference":0,"memoryReference":"0x0000000000000001"},{"name":"[0]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[0]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[1]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[1]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[2]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[2]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[3]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[3]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[4]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[4]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[5]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[5]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[6]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[6]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[7]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[7]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[8]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[8]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[9]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[9]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[10]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[10]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[11]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[11]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[12]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[12]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[13]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[13]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[14]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[14]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[15]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[15]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[16]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[16]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[17]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[17]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[18]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[18]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[19]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[19]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[20]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[20]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[21]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[21]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[22]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[22]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[23]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[23]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[24]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[24]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[25]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[25]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[26]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[26]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[27]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[27]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[28]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[28]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[29]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[29]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[30]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[30]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[31]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[31]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[32]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[32]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[33]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[33]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[34]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[34]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[35]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[35]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[36]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[36]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[37]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[37]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[38]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[38]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[39]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[39]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[40]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[40]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[41]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[41]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[42]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[42]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[43]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[43]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[44]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[44]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[45]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[45]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[46]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[46]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[47]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[47]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[48]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[48]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[49]","value":"","type":"int","evaluateName":"((int[50])*(((stmt).d)->data,c))[49]","variablesReference":0},{"name":"[Raw View]","value":"Explicit refresh required for visualized expressions","evaluateName":"[Raw View]","variablesReference":0}]},"seq":1657}
```

Comment: I might be completely off base here but I thought natvis files were for the Microsoft debugger, not gdb.

Comment: Seems I am off base, natvis has been [ported](https://github.com/asarium/gdb-natvis) to gdb. But only partially.

Comment: You could try this [Qt pretty printer](https://github.com/KDE/kdevelop/tree/master/plugins/gdb/printers) for gdb instead.